How to upload a file to OpenAI Assistant API via QT C basd code
OpenAI Assistant API allows the client to upload additional "knowledge" in a file so that the Assistant work with ChatGPT to provide more customized/private AI responses.
My client is C based code in QT Creator IDE. I use QT 6.5 which has QT classes QNetWorkManager and QNetworkRequest which provides the REST API GET/POST/PUT interface (and thus I dont need to use the curl library). I'm attempting to write wrapper functions that would approximate OpenAI's Python based OpenAI library (pip install openai). I do know how to do achieve the upload via Python OpenAI library but support in (libai) C Library is unofficial and scarce and does not cover Assistant API functions. Hence I decided to have a go at it myself.
The OpenAI API reference is pretty straighforward to implement except for one (at least for me). That is the File Upload. OpenAI reference is at: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/files/create
Specifically OpenAI states:
Upload file
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/files
My attempt to call the url via QNetWorkManager and QNetworkRequest did not work. Appreciate your help.
The following are the key excerpts of the code in QT. I stripped the code down to bare essentials to the problem only.
#define OpenAI_UPLOAD_FILE_URL "https://api.openai.com/v1/files"
/*
 * Supporting function only
 * Pretty Print API response from JSON Object
 */
void AI_Dialog::printJson(QJsonObject json){
    QJsonDocument doc(json);
    QString jsonString = doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented);
    qDebug().noquote() << jsonString.toStdString().c_str();
}

/*
 * Wrapper function to OpenAI to upload a file
 * Note: reply is defined in AI_Dialog class as QNetworkReply *reply.
 *       OpenAI_apiKey is key to OpenAI key (not shown)
 */
bool AI_Dialog::upload_file()
{
    QUrl APIurl(OpenAI_UPLOAD_FILE_URL);

    QNetworkRequest request(APIurl);
    bool status = false;

    //If not API key do not proceed
    if (this->OpenAI_apiKey.isEmpty())
        return false;

    //Setup RestAPI Header
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QByteArray("multipart/form-data"));
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + this->OpenAI_apiKey.toUtf8());


    QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

    QHttpPart valuePart;
    valuePart.setRawHeader("purpose", "assistants");
    multiPart->append(valuePart);

    valuePart.setRawHeader("file", "@contents.json");
    valuePart.setBody("bla bla");
    multiPart->append(valuePart);

    // Do REST API Post operation
    reply = this->network_access_manager.post(request, multiPart);

    //Setup REST AI completion callbacks. Mian one is ReadyRead
    status = connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, &AI_Dialog::readyRead);
    return true;
}

//Rest API callback completion for POST, GET etc to OPenAI
void AI_Dialog::readyRead()
{
    QUrl url;
    QJsonArray array;
    QJsonObject ar1;

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError){

        //Get Data from reply
        QString reply_str = reply->readAll();

        QByteArray byte_array = reply_str.toUtf8();
        QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(byte_array);
        QJsonObject obj = doc.object();

        //Debug Only
        printJson(obj);
    }
}

Result in Response (via printJson)
{
"error": {
"code": null,
"message": "'file' is a required property",
"param": null,
"type": "invalid_request_error"
}
}
Follow up : this worked (code excerpt)
QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new 
QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

QHttpPart valuePart;
valuePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "text/plain");
valuePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, "form-data; name=\"purpose\"");
valuePart.setBody("assistants");
multiPart->append(valuePart);

QHttpPart filePart;
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"Hello_There.json\"");
filePart.setBody("{bla bla}");

multiPart->append(filePart);


Does this answer your question? Upload files using QNetworkManager is not woking

It seems you're trying to use the file format for curl, which obviously doesn't make sense since this is not curl. The body part should also be the file, not some random string. You should use a proper header (I suppose QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader) and then set the contents of the file as its body.

Yes already read - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67551969/upload-files-using-qnetworkmanager-is-not-woking. In fact my code is inspired from that example. The "file" is needed in request body as it is specified in OpenAI. Indeed the curl command also uses the same keyword.  I also tried:     valuePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-postData; file=bla bla@content.json"));
but problem persists

Your code doesn't match what suggested in the linked answer, and, as already said, the @ syntax only makes sense in curl. You must provide a proper form-data syntax, with the name set to file (the field), and, most importantly, the setBody() (the actual contents) using the contents of the file to send.

It works now. The gist is to not specify "multipart/form-data" in ContentType Header. Also the specific multipart call is: `filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, "form-data; name="file"; filename="Hello_There.json"");

Following code excerpt worked for me:
QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new 
QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

QHttpPart valuePart;
valuePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "text/plain");
valuePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, "form-data; 
name=\"purpose\"");
valuePart.setBody("assistants");
multiPart->append(valuePart);

QHttpPart filePart;
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, 
"application/json");
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, "form-data; 
name=\"file\"; filename=\"Hello_There.json\"");
filePart.setBody("{bla bla}");

multiPart->append(filePart);

